# how to return a list of all integers that occur at least three times using nested loop and/or dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

how to return a list of all integers that occur at least three times using nested loop and/or dictionary? I have used .count() to find number of value in the list, but how can I use nested loop or using dictionary to do the same performance as this function.

x = 1,10,-5,10,10,-1,22,3,1,3,7,-5,22,-5,3,10,5

> > > triples(x)
> > >       [3, 10, -5]

def triples(entries):

```
out=[]
for val in entries:
    if entries.count(val) >= 3 and int(val) not in out:
        out.append(int(val))
return out
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def triples(entries):
    return [k for k, v in Counter(entries).items() if v >= 3]
```

This has linear time complexity unlike your repeated `count` approach or the nested loops you suggest.